sharpsnmp ResponseMessage for snmp v3
I am trying to build a prototype relay agent that can respond to both SNMPv2 and SNMPv3 (with authentication or encryption for the initial phase) get messages. I was trying to use ResponseMessage to build the generic reply
        if (request.Version == VersionCode.V3)
        {
            var responsePdu = new ResponsePdu(
                request.RequestId(),          // Match the request ID
                 ErrorCode.NoError,          // Indicate no error
                 0,                          // Error index
                 variables                   // Variables to return
             );

            // Construct the scope with the same context as the request
            var responseScope = new Scope(
                request.Scope.ContextEngineId, // Match the engine ID
                request.Scope.ContextName,     // Match the context name
                responsePdu                    // Attach the response PDU
            );
            resp = new ResponseMessage(
                  request.Version,
                  new Header(
                    new Integer32(request.MessageId()),
                    new Integer32(Messenger.MaxMessageSize),
                    privacy.ToSecurityLevel()
                  ),
                  new SecurityParameters(
                    request.Parameters.EngineId,
                    new Integer32(time[0]),
                    new Integer32(time[1]),
                    userName,
                    privacy.AuthenticationProvider.CleanDigest,
                    privacy.Salt),
                 new Scope(
                    request.Scope.ContextEngineId,
                    request.Scope.ContextName,
                    new ResponsePdu(
                      request.RequestId(),
                      ErrorCode.NoError,
                      0,
                      variables
                    )
                 ),
                 privacy,
                 false,
                 null
           );
        }
        else
        {
            resp =         // Create and return a response message
            new ResponseMessage(
                request.RequestId(),
                request.Version,
                request.Community(),
                ErrorCode.NoError,
                0,
                variables
            );
        }

Now this works for SNMPv2 but for V3 it throws the following error on the client side (I am using net snmp on ubuntu to verify):
when PDU is converted to byte array:
snmpget: Timeout (parse header length 78 too short: need 0)
when length is passed as null:
snmpget: Invalid message (e.g. msgFlags)
The documentation says I need use overloaded ResponseMessage constructor for v3 and I need pass length as the last parameter. How should I calculate correct length? Any hint to resolve this is much appreciated.
